# User in a variable?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and I would like to ask you something.

We have an array whose size depends on value input by user in a variable ‘arraysize’. Look at below code and comments please, is it a correct way to achieve this said be behaviour?

```
int * myArray = NULL;
int arraySize;
cout << "Enter array size: ";
cin >> arraySize;
myArray = new int[arraySize];
delete [] myArray;
```

Comment: Use a std::vector.

Comment: Reviews of working code belong to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Сhristian Hackl, hey how do you about this? that it belongs over there..

Comment: @AnatoliyFederer: By posting it over there.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Oh yeah, now i see this..still, thanks..

Comment: @ChristianHackl What do you think about useing std vector? Is there any solution..

Comment: if you are a beginner, in contrast to what many teacher or tutorials will tell you, you can forget about c-style arrays for a long time and use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. I was a beginner not so long time ago and I wish someone had told me this

Comment: @AnatoliyFederer: A solution to *what*?

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::vector` as a C++ best practice.

Comment: Can you show me please an example, how would you overwrite this code below for the "right solution". Thank you. )

Comment: Well i can show you. But learning from the documentation is better for you. I'd rather you learn from a tutorial on how to use `vector`.

Comment: i understand yes, i will do it..just wanted you to just show me an example if you have some time.. Best Regards..

Answer (score 3):

The earlier answer was a community wiki. Since you asked for an example, here's a more detailed answer.

A `std::vector` is a class belonging to the standard template library [read in detail](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

```
//since you used "using namespace std;" I'm omitting the "std::"
```

**Declaration**

```
vector< int > v; //creates a vector of integers 
vector< double > vd; //vector of double values
```

This is quite similar to `int a[/*any number*/]`.

**Inserting values**

```
v.push_back(5); //adds 5 to the end of the vector (or array of variable size)
```

---

With the above two lines you dont need to know in advance how many numbers you'll have to store.

One more sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  int myint;

  std::cout << "Please enter some integers (enter 0 to end):\n";

  do {
    std::cin >> myint;
    myvector.push_back (myint);
  } while (myint);

  std::cout << "myvector stores " << int(myvector.size()) << " numbers.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This program reads values and saves to `myvector` till `0` is entered in input.

**Iteration**

```
std::vector<int>::size_type sz = myvector.size(); //even int works here

// assign some values:
for (unsigned int i=0; i<sz; i++) myvector[i]=i;
```

**Deletion**

```
v.pop_back(); //removes last element
```